# Paw http client - chain requests

Tags: http, paw-app

Anyone have experience chaining http requests using the Paw client? The documentation is sparse. It doesn't explain how to copy cookies from one request to another. The dev may assume that we already know how, but I don't.

I'd really appreciate if someone either knows how to do that or can point me to some complete doc explaining how to.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mike. Sorry for the late reply. You'll be able to chain requests in the same session with Paw 2.1 which will be released in the very next few days. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as of the version of paw that I'm using, (2.1.1,) requests can be chained by collecting them together in a group and then selecting the group and hitting the 'send requests' button.

you can still manually select and copy cookies as 'dynamic values' from one response and paste the resulting variable in to the header of the subsequent requests, but an easier way to do this is to simply go to the 'options' tab for each request in the chain and make sure that the 'automatically send cookies' and 'store received cookies' options are checked.